# google.zxing barcode generator in iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, barcode, zxing

I want put a barcode in my page and can preview it. The barcode generator is **google.zxing** and my reporting tool is **iReport**.

But i dont know, how to configure `Image Expression` and `Expression Class` of an image in **iReport**.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/zxing/browse_thread/thread/e8fbcde52f9efd80

Comment: @AlexK: I tried that before, but it's not clear

Comment: You should at least tell us what kind of Barcode you are trying to generate...

Comment: @MarcNuri: No difference, but at least for 2D Barcode

Comment: @MasoudM.: I realize the original question was posted a couple of months ago, so you may have moved on... but the sample I posted should have all of the key ideas you need. Any chance you're still going to generate QR Codes?

Comment: I wrote an answer using `zxing` to generate the QR code in [Stack Overflow: qr-code-integration-in-jasperreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786226/qr-code-integration-in-jasperreport/47383846#47383846). If suits your requirement you can use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two key ideas are first to write a bit of Java code to create the relevant image and then to design the report to reference this code appropriately. Perhaps the simplest way to generate the image is in a scriptlet like this:

```
package com.jaspersoft.alliances.mdahlman;
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDefaultScriptlet;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRScriptletException;

public class QRCodeScriptlet extends JRDefaultScriptlet {
    public void afterDetailEval() throws JRScriptletException {
        QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
        BitMatrix matrix = null;
        try {
            matrix = writer.encode(getFieldValue("barcode_text").toString(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 256, 256);
            this.setVariableValue("BarCodeImage", MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(matrix) );
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

That's full of hard-coded ugliness, but the key ideas are all shown. Then you need to define the report like this:

1. Sample query: `select 'some text' as barcode_text` 
   I included this only to reinforce the point that my scriptlet hard-codes the field name `barcode_text`. (This is bad.)
2. Variable: `BarCodeImage` of type `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` with calculation `System`. 
   This name is hard-coded in the scriptlet too. (This is equally bad.)
3. Add to iReport's classpath:

   - The compiled scriptlet .jar file
   - core.jar (from ZXing)
   - javase.jar (from ZXing)
4. Add an Image element to the report with Expression `$V{BarCodeImage}`.

The result is a happy happy QR-code in your generated JasperReport:

[image: Generated QR-Code]

I recall a sample that I have seen which does things much more cleanly. It actually included a nice plug-in so you could easily install this functionality into iReport with minimal effort. If I can track that down, then I'll update this post. But until then this at least covers all of the critical points.

Comment: Additional there is very good guide in chapter 15, how to create scriptlet http://www.opus-college.net/devcorner/iReport-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The image expression should return any subclass of `java.awt.Image`. The easiest way to achieve this is to use your own helper class to generate the Image. You can create a static method that generates a barcode from a `String`and call that method from IReport.

In the case of ZXing I don't know the method to use, but I can tell what I use as ImageExpression using the Barbecue library.

```
        net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(
MyBarcodeGenerator.getFromString($F{field})
```

`MyBarcodeGenerator` class contains the method `getFromString(...)` that returns a `net.sourceforge.barbecue.Barcode` in my case a `net.sourceforge.barbecue.linear.code39.Code39Barcode`

The `Expression Class` is ignored.

--Edited:

To encode an Image in zxing you should use `MatrixToImageWriter`

The following code will encode a QRCode into a BufferedImage which you can use in the Image Expression field:

```
MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(new QRCodeWriter().encode("BARCODE CONTENT", BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,     400 /*Width*/, 400/*Height*/));
```